# TYPO3 custom extension register impressions in database

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I wrote an extension that picks randomly a defined number of images with link (banners) to display.

I want to count the times they get displayed (impressions). That is, after the random function has made its pick i'd like to increase the database field `impressions` for the selected entries by one.

This is the pertinent part of the domain repository:

```
public function findPartnerList($entryNumber = 6) {

    $entries = $this->createQuery()->execute()->count();
    $offset = mt_rand(0, max(0, ($entries - $entryNumber)));

    ... // code refers to a class that picks random

    $result = $query->execute();

   ... // field:impressions should get increased by one for all uid's in $result

    return $results;
}
```

- I don't know how to handle the object yielded by
  `$query->execute()`...
- I don't know how to write to the database ...
- I don't know how to increase the field `impressions` by one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should perform manipulations to your domain objects in the controller only and not in the repository - the ORM layer is just the connection between the OOP domain model world and your database.

In `WhateverController` for instance...

```
...
/** @var Whatever[] $items */
$items = $this->whateverRepository->findPartnerList();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item->setImpressions($item->getImpressions() + 1);
    $this->whateverRepository->update($item);
}
...
```

Comment: that is close enough !! `setImpressions($item->getImpressions() + 1)` had to be `increaseImpressions()` and following added to model/item.php `public function increaseImpressions() { $this->impressions += 1; }` ... your code gave a fatal error ...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However the example is already kept very generic with the `Whatever` domain object. Of course that had to be adjusted to your specific extension and class names (which I and others should not be aware of). That's why I'd opt for keeping the example generic...

Comment: `setImpressions($item->getImpressions() + 1);` stalled my site though, I don't think that's a matter of remaining generic...